Why i get this message in Statistic in Operators and Queue in WellTime that works with Asterisk
Please, help. I get this message in WellTime in Operators and Queue


And this is the error message from first picture:
mysql error: [1054: Unknown column 'from' in 'having clause'] in EXECUTE("select count(*) as count from(
        SELECT if(complete_cause='ABANDON' || complete_cause='EXITWITHTIMEOUT' || complete_cause='EXITEMPTY','@lost_calls',if( t1.agent='',concat('@',ext),t1.agent)) as agent_res,
        sum(1) as count_all,
        sum(if(t1.call_type='in',1,0)) as count_in,
        sum(if(t1.call_type in ('out', 'out_qcb'),1,0)) as count_out,
        sum(if(t1.call_type='ext',1,0)) as count_ext,
        sum(if(t1.call_type='in',to_complete,0)) as time_in,
        sum(if(t1.call_type in ('out', 'out_qcb'),to_complete,0)) as time_out,
        sum(if(t1.call_type='ext',to_complete,0)) as time_ext,
        sum(to_complete) as time_total,
        max(if(t1.call_type='in', 0, to_answer)) as max_answer
        FROM `call` t1 
        WHERE complete_cause != 'ABANDON' and complete_cause != 'EXITWITHTIMEOUT' and complete_cause != 'EXITEMPTY' AND t1.agent != ''  AND (utime  between 1730667600 and 1731618000 )  AND ( (1=2  OR ( t1.ext = '9165682305' )  OR ( t1.agent = '9165682305' )  OR ( t1.subscriber = '9165682305' ) ) ) and (1=1)
        GROUP BY agent_res HAVING 1=1  AND ( `from` LIKE ('%9165682305%') ) ) as result")

Maybe it's because i redacted the asterisk extensions_custome.conf, here is the code from there
[ivr-25-custom]

exten => h,1,Noop(${CALLERID(dnid)})
exten => h,n,gotoif($["${CDR(dstchannel)}"=""]?:noop)
exten => h,n,System(/opt/ast/conv.sh info@ast.ru "${CDR(src)}" "${CALLERID(name)}" "${DIALSTATUS}" "${FILE}" 2 "${CALLERID(dnid)}")
exten => h,n(noop),Noop(bye)

[ivr-105-custom]

exten => h,1,Noop(${CALLERID(dnid)})
exten => h,n,gotoif($["${CDR(dstchannel)}"=""]?:noop)
exten => h,n,System(/opt/ast/conv.sh info@ast.ru "${CDR(src)}" "${CALLERID(name)}" "${DIALSTATUS}" "${FILE}" 2 "${CALLERID(dnid)}")
exten => h,n(noop),Noop(bye)

[ivr-112-custom]

exten => h,1,Noop(${CALLERID(dnid)})
exten => h,n,gotoif($["${CDR(dstchannel)}"=""]?:noop)
exten => h,n,System(/opt/ast/conv.sh info@ast.ru "${CDR(src)}" "${CALLERID(name)}" "${DIALSTATUS}" "${FILE}" 2 "${CALLERID(dnid)}")
exten => h,n(noop),Noop(bye)

I really don't know why i get this message. I mean why this message is pop up. I don't do nothing in mysql and boom, this happens. Help me, please.
